# "not be permitted access" vs. "not be permitted to access"

Tags: differences, infinitives

I was wondering is it right to say something this way:

> You will not be "permitted access" to the work you produce.

Isn't it better to say it this way?

> You will not be permitted to access to the work you produce.

I've learned that when two verbs are used in a row, the latter comes with a TO before it or an -ING after it.

Comment: Btw, *permitted access to* is an odd construction; *permitted to access* is vastly preferred.

Comment: @Kris, why do you say that, I wonder? _permitted access to_ doesn't strike me as odd at all and it's [a](http://www.lse.ac.uk/ideas/Assets/Documents/exec-msc-docs/LSEAlumniBenefits.pdf) [common](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2015/jul/01/whitehall-access-outsourcing-contracts-two-thirds) [enough](https://www.pressreader.com/uk/the-press-and-journal-moray/20180604/281870119125958) [phrasing](https://www.ukdataservice.ac.uk/get-data/how-to-access/registration/commercialusers). (All my links are to UK sources; there may _possibly_ be some transatlantic variance.)

Comment: @user316660 All else aside, the second _to_ in the second sentence is out of place; you should get rid of it, making: _You will not be permitted to access the work you produce._

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine; ***access*** is used as a noun in the former, and as a verb (infinitive) in the latter.

**Note:** The verb *permit* is followed by an infinitive form of a verb (eg: to access) and not followed by a gerund (i-e ING-form of a verb, eg: permitted accessing).

Comment: Then how is the first sentence "fine"?

Comment: @Kris access is used as a noun in the former; You will not be permitted [Verb] access [Noun] to the work you produce.

Comment: But you have said *permit* is always followed by an infinitive. That probably needs qualifying.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yup, that requires to be edited a bit more.. ^^